# Project trying to load system.web that actually no need (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm making an `xamarin` android project with `asp.net web api`. I put api project and android project in same solution. Android project get data from the api through data service. But when I added `zxing` NuGet package and I build the project this error came. Do the project really need this assembly? I guess not. But suddenly the project trying to load this assembly.

So, I got this error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
Could not load assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
for Android profile? File name: 'System.Web.dll' at
Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at
Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel) at
Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()
```

This error make the project can't be build, debug and run.

At first android project didn't need this reference.

I did add `system.web` references to my project, but after I added the reference this message warning showed up:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "System.Web", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures.
>   Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your
>   project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor
>   architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.  ShopDiaryApp

At first project no need this reference. but now why they trying to load one? they make this warning uncomfortable and afraid it will cause problem at the end.

Any ideas to remove this warning? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's "NuGet", not "nugget", but ignoring that, which package are you using? There are more than a few ZXing packages, not all of which are actively maintained.

Comment: ZXing.Net.Mobile..
Sorry for that NuGet things :)

Comment: When you say "I'm making an xamarin android project with asp.net web api", can you clarify that? If you're using anything WebAPI directly in a Xamarin project, and not targeting .NET Core, you're going to wind up with System.Web references, since WebAPI is built on top of ASP.NET.

Comment: I build the web api service in the same solution. The android project getting data from web api through data service.